# How to target first td of every row with pure JS?

Tags: javascript

I tried to change the color of the first td element in each row to red.

HTML:

```
<table id="test">
<tr>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>test3</td>
    <td>test4</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

I tried this JS:

```
var tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

tr.firstChild.style.color = 'red';
```

No Jquery please.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use rows and cells to access the rows and columns of the table. See below code,

```
var table = document.getElementById('test');
for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
   var firstCol = table.rows[i].cells[0]; //first column
   firstCol.style.color = 'red'; // or anything you want to do with first col
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/QNEyx/

Comment: This is how it's done with the built-in browser API. That being said, using this in production is senseless as it's trivial to create better (shorter, more readable) API in JavaScript.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas If the OP wants to reuse this, they can figure out how to put it into a function. That's not the point of the question/answer

Comment: @ŠimeVidas This answer is very specific to this question _How to target first td of every row with pure JS?_ The purpose of this question could be anything from learning to prod.

Answer (score 8):

Parsing with JS could be costly, if you are fine achieving the same with the CSS, then here you go.

```
#test tr td:nth-of-type(1) {
   color: red;
}
```

Or

```
#test tr td:first-child {
   color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As said in another reply, css is the natural way to accomplish this.

As you are stuck with js, you can use js to inject a stylesheet in your page:

```
var styleNode=document.createElement("style");
document.head.appendChild(styleNode);
var cssString="#test tr td:first-child {color: red;}";
if (styleNode.styleSheet) { // IE
  styleNode.styleSheet.cssText = cssString;
}
else {
  styleNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cssString));
}
```

The benefit of using a stylesheet is that you avoid race conditions (case when the table is built dynamically).

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to do this with pure JS for learning purposes. Though your answer is helpful too in another sense.

Comment: @dzumla011 My answer is pure javascript! (using js to create nodes dynamically)

Comment: Yea but I wanted to target the first td with JS directly.

Comment: I'm sure this works, but why bother adding a stylesheet? Why not just declare the CSS in the first place with `#test.specialClass tr td:first-child {color: red;}` and then add the class "specialClass" to the table?

Comment: @Ian simply because the OP wanted pure js... I think he made this clear

Comment: @Christophe Haha I understand that, but you're still using CSS to apply the style instead of accessing the `.style` property. And it doesn't mean things can't be combined anyways

Comment: @Ian I am using js to create a style node that will apply a css rule. Please don't tell me that document.createElement is not js :-) I often use this technique when I need to include a variable in the stylesheet (imagine the color being a variable instead of always being red).

Comment: @Christophe I'm not trying to say that isn't JS, but the fact that you're using a CSS stylesheet/rule, even dynamically, doesn't count as "pure JS" to me. Like I said, I'm sure this works, not doubting that. But what happens when you want to remove this style? I don't think removing the style tag would get rid of the style

Comment: @Ian quoting you ;-) "There are multiple ways to approach a problem. This is one option...a very valid option. If..."

Comment: @Christophe I am **not** questioning the validity of your answer. I am questioning certain things about it, and wanted to know your reasoning. The whole "pure css" thing was brought up by you, so I answered that